# Complex matrix in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a problem with this Python code:

```
A = np.zeros((2*M + 2,nt))
A[1, :] = d[0,0] * np.ones((1,nt))
```

where `d[0,0]` is complex.  I received this error:

```
ComplexWarning: Casting complex values to real discards the imaginary part
```

during

```
A[1, :] = d[0,0] * np.ones((1,nt))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because by default `numpy` array holds zeros which is `int` type and you are trying to assign a complex array to integer array. If you write `A = np.zeros((2*M+2, nt), dtype=np.complex)` it should fix the problem. `dtype` parameter basically tells numpy to cast elements complex 0 which is actually `0+0.j`.

Comment: By default `numpy` arrays are `float64`, not `int`

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to compute a *complex* valued array `A`, or a *real* valued array `A`?  If the former, then declare `A` as:

```
A = np.zeros((2*M + 2,nt), dtype=complex)
```

Otherwise, cast your complex value `d[0, 0]` to a real using:

```
A[1, :] = (1+4j).real * np.ones((1,1))
```